# Relacion entre tablas (hasOne)

Tags: cakephp

Tengo 2 tablas una de imágenes que pertenecen a varias tablas diferentes y en la otra tabla la referencio por id_imagen con el id de la tabla imágenes.

En el modelo de imágenes he puesto:

```
$this->hasOne('Documentos')
     ->setName('Documentos')
     ->setDependent(true);
```

Y en el modelo de la tabla he puesto:

```
$this->belongsTo('Imagenes')
     ->setForeignKey('id_imagen');
```

En teoría con esto relaciono las 2 tablas pero no se si lo estoy haciendo bien.
Luego otra duda que tengo para mostrar el nombre de la imagen, que es un campo dentro de la tabla de imágenes que se llama imagen tendría que hacer algo como `$Documentos->imagen;`

Uso la ultima versión de CakePHP

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré la solución, por si alguien le interesa:

Tabla Documentos:

> id | id_imagen | titulo | texto

```
$this->hasOne('Imagenes')
     ->setBindingKey('id_imagen')
     ->setForeignKey('id');
```

Tabla Imágenes:

> id | tabla | imagen | tipo

```
$this->belongsTo('Documentos')
      ->setForeignKey('id_imagen')
      ->setJoinType('INNER');
```

Relación:

> Documentos.id_imagen = Imagenes.id

Controlador Documentos:

```
public function Documento() {
    $documentos = TableRegistry::get('Documentos');
    $documentos = $documentos->find('all')
                             ->contain(['Imagenes']);
    $this->set('documentos', $documentos);
}
```

Vista:

```
<?= $documento->imagen->imagen; ?>
```