# Undefined property: Cake\ORM\Query

Tags: cakephp

Tengo una pregunta relacionada con esta otra duda que plantee y al final encontré la solución:

[Relacion entre tablas (hasOne)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176359/relacion-entre-tablas-hasone/176484#176484)

Cuando quiero hacer lo mismo pero que solo muestre un registro según el id que le pase a la función, me devuelve el siguiente error en todos los campos de la consulta:

> Notice (8): Undefined property: Cake\ORM\Query::$id
>   [APP/Template/Documentos/documento.ctp, line 23]

Lo que hago es en el controlador de Documentos creo una función Documento, para que muestre el detalle de un documento:

```
public function escudo($idDocumento) {
    $documentos = TableRegistry::get('Documentos');
    $documento = $documentos->find()
                            ->where(['Documentos.id' => $idDocumento])
                            ->contain(['Imagenes']);
    /*debug($documento);*/
    $this->set('documento', $documento);
}
```

La consulta se monta bien y realmente he comprobado que $idDocumento contiene el valor del id, pero lo muestra como un objeto, así se ve si hago un debug de $idDocumento:

> '4'

y si hago un debug de $documento:

> ....
>
> 'sql' => 'SELECT Documentos.id AS ..... WHERE Documentos.id = :c0'
>
> 'params' => [         ':c0' => [          'value' => (int) 4,             'type' =>
>   'integer',            'placeholder' => 'c0'       ]   ], 
>   .....

Ese :c0 es como una variable, no entiendo muy bien lo que pasa pero no lo interpreta la vista.

Comment: El `:c0` es un _placeholder_ que se va a reemplazar con la variable que va a usar la query. Se usa para evitar problemas de injección de SQL.

Comment: Entonces cuando yo hago un `<?= $documento->id; ?>`¿ por que me devuelve el error de Undefined property?

Comment: No conozco el ORM de Cake, pero si corres `echo get_class($documento);` seguro que te da una idea.

Comment: si hago `get_class($documento);` Me devuelve Cake\ORM\Query que no me dice mucho

Answer (score 0):

Bueno encontré la solución era poner `->first()` en la función de Documento:

```
public function documento($idDocumento) {
    $documentos = TableRegistry::get('Documentos');
    $documento = $documentos->find()
                            ->where(['Documentos.id' => $idDocumento])
                            ->contain(['Imagenes'])
                            ->first();
    /*debug($documento);*/
    $this->set('documento', $documento);
}
```